# Plotting a function based of a complicated integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I would like to have help in making a plot of a complicated function based a definite integral.

[image]
[image]
[image: this is supposed to be] - desired graph

My calculation:

[image]

```
ClearAll[F, z];
F[z_] := 0.5*(1 + Erf[z/Sqrt[2]]);
q[B_, g_, m_] := 
  (1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*
     Integrate[F[z]^(-1 + m)/E^(0.5*((-Sqrt[B])*g + z)^2), {z, -1000, 1000}];
p[B_, g_, m_] := 1 - q[B, g, m];
Plot[{p[B, 0.2, 8]}, {Log[B, 2], -4, 4}]
```

First: Log[B,2] - Error.

Second: It's very long considers.

How to make my plot in the *Mathematica*?

Comment: added to question

Comment: `Plot[{p[B, 0.2, 8]}, {Log[B, 2], -4, 4}]` isn't syntactically correct. Take a look at the plot range specification on the docs

Comment: I think you might want to use `Plot[{p[B, 0.2, 8]}, {B, 1/16, 16}]`

Comment: Also you could try to translate `It fails with an error. long considered?` into Linear-B and then backwards.Damn @m_goldberg you spoiled my joke :)

Comment: @belisarius. My bad and I express my profound regret. Sometimes my aggressive editing makes things worse rather than better, especially when I truly only guessing what the OP intends.

Comment: How do I then count on the xAxis `Log[B, 2]`? I'm a noob in mathematica.

Comment: @belisarius. I have restored some of the OP original prose to the question.

Comment: @m_goldberg Remind me that I love you if I my Alzheimer gets worse. :D

Comment: @instantia Please take a look at the first  m_goldberg's comment up there

Comment: @belisarius. Just where does that last comment on yours lie on a sarcasm scale of 0 = not at all and 10 = cutting right to jugular.

Comment: I tried so
`Plot[{p[Reduce[Log[k, 2] == t, k], 0.2, 8]}, {t, -4, 4}]`. Error: NIntegrate::inumr and Reduce::ratnz.
I don't understand :(

Comment: I'm a fool. I do not need no `Log[B, 2]` :) thanks to all

Comment: @instantia Please see my answer. Your book contains an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the graph in your book contains an error. When we look closely at the graph of Alexei, then we see that for `m=8` and `g=0.2`, the graph crosses the y-axis at 0.84. In the picture in your book, this is not the case and the crossing is at `{0, 0.65}` (the plot is log-scaled!). Additionally, Alexei's graph ends in `{4, 0.67}` while in your book this is the point isn't even on the graph. Instead, it contains the point `{3, 0.1}`.

To cut is short: Although you book claims that it depicts `g=0.2`, I believe it rather used `g=1`.

Additionally, note that you can integrate from `-Infinity` to `Infinity` in your code. `NIntegrate` can handle this. To make this a complete answer:

```
f[z_] := 1/2 (1 + Erf[z/Sqrt[2]]);
Plot[f[z], {z, -10, 10}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[q];
q[B_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
 1 - (1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*
   NIntegrate[
    Exp[-1/2 (z - g*Sqrt[B])^2]*f[z]^(-1 + m), {z, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}]

LogPlot[Evaluate[q[2^x, 1, #] & /@ {8, 128, 512}], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.1, 1}}, 
 GridLines -> {None, {.2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"m=8", "m=128", "m=512"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Addtionally to your "Additionally", integrating from `-Infinity` to `Infinity` is usually handled better than from `-1000` to `1000` in such an integral.  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows:

```
    ClearAll[F, z];
F[z_] := 0.5*(1 + Erf[z/Sqrt[2]]);
p[lgB_, g_, m_] := 
  1 - (1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*
    NIntegrate[
     F[z]^(-1 + m)/E^(0.5*((-2^(lgB/2))*g + z)^2), {z, -1000, 1000}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 12];
Plot[{p[lgB, 0.2, 8]}, {lgB, -4, 4}]
```

yielding this

[image]

The key points are tha (i) I substituded `B=^lgB`, thus, introduced a new variable, `lgB`that you probably have head in mind, and (ii) I used `NIntegrate`instead of `Integrate`.

Have fun!

Comment: This looks odd because the *desired graph* seems to have a log-scale at the y-axis and the `m=8` curve seems to contain the point `{0.1, 3}` which doesn't go along with your graph.